# Ext.net databinding extension method

Tags: ext.net

Yeah, I have the unfortunate situation of having to go into a project that makes use of ext.net.

There is a GridPanel with several columns, a couple of these are bound to datetime properties like this:

```
<ext:DateColumn Header="Started time" DataIndex="DateStarted" Format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

Now, I ned to run an extension method, ToUniversalTime(), on the property DateStarted.

It seems I can not change DataIndex="DateStarted" to DataIndex="DateStarted.ToUniversalTime()"

Comment: why not call the method when filling the data source?

Comment: "Yeah, I have the unfortunate situation of having to go into a project that makes use of ext.net."... more feedback regarding that comment would be helpful.

Comment: Meywd that cannot be done. The datasource is a list of objects. It's in the component you work with that you specify what information you want to show in that component. To specify an extension method, which you can do with ordinary asp.net controls, you can't do with ext.net.

Comment: geoffery.mcgill, everything I've seen about ext.net is horrible. Just start with the fact it does not integrate with visual studio. Some components properties does not work so you have to do some parts, height, width, does not work fully so you have to specify that in style sheets. Then we have the fact that it's not backwards compatible and you have to keep it up to date for it not to look to bad in new browser versions, that is not fun with a crap product that is not backwards compatible. To bad I'm stuck with this shit.

Comment: geoffery, a product that is not backwards compatible = a lot of work when you have to update that product in your applications...

Comment: @Johan what I meant was that you can do a for loop on the list of objects, update the dates, and then send it to the control to be bound

Comment: @Johan what do you mean under "it does not integrate with visual studio"? what integration do you mean? Height and Width properties works fine, just note that only pixels are allowed otherwise use appropriate layout. "it's not backwards compatible" - can you elobarate it?

Comment: It does not integrate with visual studio, you can't render it, view it while programming. You have to build the project and go to the website to look at it.

Comment: It's not backwards compatible. If you upgrade to a later version, you get a lot of ext.net stuff that no longer works.

Comment: I know I can manipulate the data before I give it to the control, but this is presentation logic, the ext.net control should be able to handle it since ms asp.net components can.

Comment: About VS integration. Ext.Net is based on Sencha ExtJS. ExtJS is javascript toolkit. All widgets are rendered using javascript code, not HTML. Therefore it is very difficult to create VS designer support (it works with pure HTML only)

Comment: About backwards compatible. As I said before, Ext.Net is based on Sencha ExtJS toolkit. Therefore Ext.Net depends from ExtJS changes. But all breaking changes are described in http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/BREAKING_CHANGES/ and can be solved by simple find/replace procedure (mostly)

Comment: Blaming something else does not change the fact that ext.net does not support backwards compatibility making it an unreliable product that everyone should stay away from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about this one.

I got an answer from Vladimir Ext.NET - Dev Team, support for this is to be added in version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Renderer tag on your column

```
    <ext:DateColumn Header="Started time" DataIndex="DateStarted" Format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" >
        <Renderer Fn="myRenderer" />
    </ext:DateColumn >
```

Call a Direct Method or implement your extension method in JavaScript

```
    var myRenderer = function (value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            return stuff here;
        };
```